# Background image not appearing on iPhone

Tags: css

The background imge (svg) appears on all devices and browsers except on iPhone.

I tried to change photo formats, turned the picture to not progressive,
chenged "background-image" to "background" on css, but nothing helped.

CSS:

```
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
    ), url(img/lobby.svg); 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: center; 
  height: 100vh; 
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: try this for triage: 1. remove rgba stuff leave only the url(). share what is the result? 2. try url(/img/lobby.svg) (with "/")

Comment: Spasibo Sergey for your advice:) It was important for me to maintain the existing design so I found a solution that made it possible to leave the rgba by addition of prefix -webkit- following way: background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(img/lobby.jpg);